# Get selected value in SelectOneMenu box

Tags: javascript

This statement is not giving me value selected in selectonemenu box:

```
document.getElementById("purchaseOrderForm:supplierName").value;
```

How to do it?

Comment: show us more of ur code or better would be to provide a fiddle link

Comment: ID in selector can't contain :

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat nope, `:` can be used

Answer (score 2):

seems to be working for me

```
<form>
    <select id="purchaseOrderForm:supplierName">
        <option value="value 1">value 1 </option>
        <option value="value 2">value 2 </option>
        <option value="value 3">value 3 </option>
    </select>
   <input type="button" id="btn_showValue" value="show value"/>
</form>

document.getElementById("btn_showValue").onclick = function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("purchaseOrderForm:supplierName").value)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLrLg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/fnyR7/2/)

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="purchaseOrderForm:supplierName">
        <option value="1">Order 1 </option>
        <option value="2">Order 2 </option>
        <option value="3">Order 3 </option>
    </select>
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="getvalue();"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function getvalue()
{
var e = document.getElementById("purchaseOrderForm:supplierName");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; //the value of the selected option
alert(str);

var e = document.getElementById("purchaseOrderForm:supplierName");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; //the text of the selected option
alert(str);
}
```

Comment: purchaseOrderForm is my form id and supplierName is my selectOneMenu id. My javascript file is purchaseOrderValidation.js inside that I have written function. I tried both of your answer but it is of no use. Please guide me for the same.